# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException with GeoServer, OpenLayer

Tags: java, tomcat, exception, openlayers, geoserver

The GeoServer has a layer in the projection *EPSG:4326*.

The query is *success* (projection *EPSG:3857*):
http://domain:8080/geoserver/agroupr/wms?SERVICE=wfs&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&TYPENAME=Fields_Umetskiy_2013_Z&srsName=**EPSG%3A3857**&cql_filter=%22FEATUREID%22%20%3D%20%2768644-2199%27&r=0.07534018825621613

The query is *exception* (projection *EPSG:4326*):
http://domain:8080/geoserver/agroupr/wms?SERVICE=wfs&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&TYPENAME=Fields_Umetskiy_2013_Z&srsName=**EPSG%3A4326**&cql_filter=%22FEATUREID%22%20%3D%20%2768644-2199%27&r=0.7545296346447807

Request with *original projection* does not work!

The error returned:

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://domain:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
    <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
        <ows:ExceptionText>
            java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
        </ows:ExceptionText>
    </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

*Configuration*:
Version GeoServer: *2.10.0*
Memory usage: *689 MB / 1 GB*
Version JVM: *Oracle Corporation: 1.8.0_161 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM)*
Maximum amount of memory JAI: *910 MB*

*Log*:

```
2018-04-25 14:21:32,301 WARN [geoserver.web] - Unable to find property: 'format.wms.application/vnd.google-earth.kml' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage]. Locale: null, style: null
2018-04-25 14:21:32,301 WARN [geoserver.web] - Unable to find property: 'format.wms.rss' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage]. Locale: null, style: null
2018-04-25 14:21:44,220 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.xml.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:742)
    at org.geotools.xml.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:609)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.GML3OutputFormat.encode(GML3OutputFormat.java:302)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.GML3OutputFormat.write(GML3OutputFormat.java:279)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.write(WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.java:196)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:991)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleSimpleCORS(CorsFilter.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.gml3.simple.GML3FeatureCollectionEncoderDelegate$GML3Delegate.setSrsNameAttribute(GML3FeatureCollectionEncoderDelegate.java:145)
    at org.geotools.gml2.simple.FeatureCollectionEncoderDelegate.buildSrsAttributes(FeatureCollectionEncoderDelegate.java:241)
    ... 106 more
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Update: log (geotools-dev)**

```
2018-04-27 15:28:32,851 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2018-04-27 15:28:32,866 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Read lock: file:/D:/Geoserver/data/Karta_poley_zemlepolzovateley/Fields_Umetskiy_2013_Z.shp by org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader
2018-04-27 15:28:32,866 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Shapefile Reader has been opened. Number open: 1
2018-04-27 15:28:32,866 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - IndexFile has been opened. Number open: 1
2018-04-27 15:28:32,866 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Read lock: file:/D:/Geoserver/data/Karta_poley_zemlepolzovateley/Fields_Umetskiy_2013_Z.shx by org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.IndexFile
2018-04-27 15:28:32,866 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Reading from file...
2018-04-27 15:28:32,866 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Read lock: file:/D:/Geoserver/data/Karta_poley_zemlepolzovateley/Fields_Umetskiy_2013_Z.dbf by org.geotools.data.shapefile.dbf.DbaseFileReader
2018-04-27 15:28:32,866 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Dbase File Reader has been opened. Number open: 1
2018-04-27 15:28:32,866 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Filling buffer...
2018-04-27 15:28:32,866 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Read lock: file:/D:/Geoserver/data/Karta_poley_zemlepolzovateley/Fields_Umetskiy_2013_Z.shp by org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader
2018-04-27 15:28:32,866 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Shapefile Reader has been closed. Number open: 0
2018-04-27 15:28:32,866 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Read lock: file:/D:/Geoserver/data/Karta_poley_zemlepolzovateley/Fields_Umetskiy_2013_Z.shx by org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.IndexFile
2018-04-27 15:28:32,866 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - IndexFile has been closed. Number open: 0
2018-04-27 15:28:32,866 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Read lock: file:/D:/Geoserver/data/Karta_poley_zemlepolzovateley/Fields_Umetskiy_2013_Z.dbf by org.geotools.data.shapefile.dbf.DbaseFileReader
2018-04-27 15:28:32,866 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Dbase File Reader has been closed. Number open: 0
2018-04-27 15:28:32,866 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = wfs
    version = 1.1.0
    baseUrl = http://domain:8080/geoserver/
    query[0]:
        filter = [ FEATUREID = 68644-2199 ]
        srsName = EPSG:4326
        typeName[0] = {localhost/agroupr}Fields_Umetskiy_2013_Z
    outputFormat = text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1
    resultType = results
2018-04-27 15:28:32,913 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2018-04-27 15:28:32,913 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2018-04-27 15:28:32,913 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Read lock: file:/D:/Geoserver/data/Karta_poley_zemlepolzovateley/Fields_Umetskiy_2013_Z.shp by org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader
2018-04-27 15:28:32,913 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Shapefile Reader has been opened. Number open: 1
2018-04-27 15:28:32,913 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - IndexFile has been opened. Number open: 1
2018-04-27 15:28:32,913 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Read lock: file:/D:/Geoserver/data/Karta_poley_zemlepolzovateley/Fields_Umetskiy_2013_Z.shx by org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.IndexFile
2018-04-27 15:28:32,913 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Reading from file...
2018-04-27 15:28:32,913 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Read lock: file:/D:/Geoserver/data/Karta_poley_zemlepolzovateley/Fields_Umetskiy_2013_Z.dbf by org.geotools.data.shapefile.dbf.DbaseFileReader
2018-04-27 15:28:32,913 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Dbase File Reader has been opened. Number open: 1
2018-04-27 15:28:32,913 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Filling buffer...
2018-04-27 15:28:32,929 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Read lock: file:/D:/Geoserver/data/Karta_poley_zemlepolzovateley/Fields_Umetskiy_2013_Z.shp by org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader
2018-04-27 15:28:32,929 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Shapefile Reader has been closed. Number open: 0
2018-04-27 15:28:32,929 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Read lock: file:/D:/Geoserver/data/Karta_poley_zemlepolzovateley/Fields_Umetskiy_2013_Z.shx by org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.IndexFile
2018-04-27 15:28:32,929 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - IndexFile has been closed. Number open: 0
2018-04-27 15:28:32,929 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Read lock: file:/D:/Geoserver/data/Karta_poley_zemlepolzovateley/Fields_Umetskiy_2013_Z.dbf by org.geotools.data.shapefile.dbf.DbaseFileReader
2018-04-27 15:28:32,929 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Dbase File Reader has been closed. Number open: 0
2018-04-27 15:28:32,929 ERROR [org.geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.xml.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:742)
    at org.geotools.xml.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:609)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.GML3OutputFormat.encode(GML3OutputFormat.java:302)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.GML3OutputFormat.write(GML3OutputFormat.java:279)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.write(WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.java:196)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:991)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:419)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.gml3.simple.GML3FeatureCollectionEncoderDelegate$GML3Delegate.setSrsNameAttribute(GML3FeatureCollectionEncoderDelegate.java:145)
    at org.geotools.gml2.simple.FeatureCollectionEncoderDelegate.buildSrsAttributes(FeatureCollectionEncoderDelegate.java:241)
    at org.geotools.gml2.simple.FeatureCollectionEncoderDelegate.encodeValue(FeatureCollectionEncoderDelegate.java:192)
    at org.geotools.gml2.simple.FeatureCollectionEncoderDelegate.encodeFeature(FeatureCollectionEncoderDelegate.java:176)
    at org.geotools.gml2.simple.FeatureCollectionEncoderDelegate.encode(FeatureCollectionEncoderDelegate.java:130)
    at org.geotools.xml.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:739)
    ... 103 more
```

Comment: To improve readability please highlight the difference in the queries.

Comment: Also share the geoserver version in use

Comment: The srsName parameter is optional and used to reproject a layer. Given that the layer is already in projection 4326, try your REST call without the srsName parameter when you want the data in 4326. Post the result.

Comment: The result is the same - an exception: *java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException*. The same stack in the log.

Comment: turn on verbose exceptions and logging level to geotools-dev and try again, then update question with log file and exception.

Comment: Updated question: specified version and added debug log